# Skip a task when running another task

Tags: gradle, skip

I added a task to my gradle project:

```
task deploy() {
    dependsOn "build"
    // excludeTask "test"  <-- something like this

    doFirst {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Now the `build` task always runs before the `deploy` task. This is fine because the build task has many steps included. Now I want to explicitly disable one of these included tasks.

Usually I disable it from command line with

```
gradle deploy -x test
```

How can I exclude the `test` task programmatically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to configure tasks graph rather than configure the `deploy` task itself. Here's the piece of code you need:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(deploy)) {
        test.enabled = false
    }
}
```

WARNING: this will skip the actions defined by the `test` task, it will NOT skip tasks that `test` depends on. Thus this is not the same behavior as passing `-x test` on the command line

Comment: Hi, I know this was answered a long time ago, but I am trying this now, using gradle 6.0.1 and I don't manage to get that working. My scenario is a bit different, would you be able to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460651/gradle-custom-task-that-depends-on-build-task-without-testing? Thank you

Comment: Note that this will still execute tasks that `test` declared as depending on. Thus this is not the same behavior as passing `-x test` on the command line. I haven't found a way to skip a task and all its "dependencies", I would love to know one

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your deploy task does, but it probably just shouldn't depend on the 'build' task. The 'build' task is a very coarse grained lifecycle task that includes tons of stuff you probably don't want.

Instead it should correctly define its inputs (probably the artifacts that you wanna deploy) and then Gradle will only run the necessary tasks to build those inputs. Then you no longer need any excludes.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. Here is how I prevent "test" from running when I run "intTest" and want the ITs to run alone:

```
test {
    onlyIf { !gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("intTest") }
}
```

An alternative that doesn't depend on certain tasks being run explicitly:

```
test {
    onlyIf { !gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(":intTest") || gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(":check") }
}
```