# gradle custom task that depends on build task without testing

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using gradle 6.0.1

I am trying to write my on task, but I want first the the build task is executed but without tests.

I tried (from build.gradle):

```
task startEnv(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['build']
    doLast {
        // START ENV CODE
    }
}
```

However, I don't manage to find a way to call build without running tests, as I would run

> gradle build -x test

Is it possible to achieve this functionality?

Another option I can use, is to check inside my startEnv task whether build already exists and run this task only if build exists - Is there a way to query whether build exists? (this is a multi module projects, so I am not sure it is enough to check whether build directory exists on the root project).

I followed the comments and tried the solution mentioned at [Skip a task when running another task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649712/skip-a-task-when-running-another-task)

I added to build.gradle:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(startEnv)) {
        println("DEBUG1")
        test.enabled = false
    }
}

task startEnv(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['build']
    doLast {
       // START ENV CODE
    }
}
```

But when I run ./gradlew startEnv - it still fails with some tests that in current phase I know they should fail.
I can see the DEBUG1 print when I execute this command but the build fails with tests that are failing.

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip a task when running another task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649712/skip-a-task-when-running-another-task)

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried that, but it does not help. I am updating my question

Comment: Why task `startEnv` is of type `GradleBuild` - it seems it's too heavy. Instead define a simple task and set dependencies. Also, are you sure `test.enabled` refers to a task?   Please try `project.tasks.test.enabled = false`. This may make a difference.

Comment: As Opal said, just depend on build, similar to this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907275/gradle-custom-task-which-runs-multiple-tasks. Note that it might be possible to depend on more specific subtasks than build, and then you might not need to exclude the test task.

Comment: @Opal At first I did try this approach, however the build was not running. I am having a multi module project which the top build.gradle actually is not doing much, when I did that approach and I set 'dependsOn "build"' the modules (sub projects) did not build and I found on that same thread that using GradleBuild task works well. I will try now the approach with project.tasks.test.enabled and will update. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Opal, I tried project.tasks.test.enabled, but it didn't help, so I took on step further and tried to iterate over the subprojects and for each subproject set test.enabled = false, but it also didn't help, I still got the tests failing and failing my build fail